# Submit form through ajax and callback an alert

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, forms

I submit a form using ajax request. The form is actually inside a modal popup. The submission works well. But I want it to show an alert that said the form is submitted and close the current modal. Here is my code:

```
$('#btnBookRoom').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/Booking/BookRoom",
    type: "POST",
    data: $('#frmRoomBooking').serialize(),
    datatype: "json",
    sucess: function(data) {
      alert('Room Booking Success');
      $('#roomBookingModal').modal('hide');
    }

  });
});
```

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult BookRoom(RoomBookingInputModel roomBooking)
        {
            var domain = new RoomBooking
            {
                GuestId = roomBooking.GuestId
            };

            db.RoomBookings.Add(domain);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return Json(domain, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

The alert doest shows and the modal also not hiding.

Comment: can you check your method get called ?? serverside method get called or not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sucess` isn't a valid callback in jQuery's [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method. You need to change it to `success`.

Or better, use promise API to bind a success handler (as AJAX callbacks are already deprecated):

```
$.ajax({  ... })
  .then(function() {
      alert('Room Booking Success');
      $('#roomBookingModal').modal('hide');
  });
```